# Getting an error in Python: Cannot assign to operator error

Tags: python

Trying to code an assignment however I'm getting an error saying cannot assign to operator. This is the code:

```
x5=0.3;x6=0.8;x7=1
x8=(x5+x6)/2;x9=(x6+x7)/2
if fx(x6,a)>fx(x5,a) and fx(x6,a)>fx(x7,a):
  x5=x8 and x7=x9
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: `x5=x8 and x7=x9` - What do you expect this to do?

Comment: Are you trying to do two assignments here `x5=x8 and x7=x9?` You cannot use `and` in this context, just write two lines

Comment: This is some *really* unpythonic code. Lines are free...there's no reason to cram a bunch of stuff on one line with `;`. If you want to do multiple assignments on one line use something more readable like: `x5, x6, x7 = 0.3, 0.8, 1`. Or better yet, just use three lines.

Comment: `x5=x8 and x7=x9` is interpreted as `x5 = (x8 and x7) = x9` which is illegal (because you *Cannot assign to operator*). You can. however, do `x5, x7 = x8, x9`

Answer (score 0):

`and` is a reserved keyword in Python that corresponds to the operation of anding two variables. That is, `and` is an operation that has a result, it does not mean 'do this and also do this'.

To fix your code just change it to be:

```
x5=0.3
x6=0.8
x7=1
x8=(x5+x6)/2
x9=(x6+x7)/2

if fx(x6,a)>fx(x5,a) and fx(x6,a)>fx(x7,a):
  x5=x8
  x7=x9
```

This structure translated to english would roughly say "**If** fx(x6,a) is greater than fx(x5, a) **and** fx(x6,a) > f7(x7,a) **then** x5 = x8, x7 = x9."

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot separate two expressions using `and` as you are doing in this line:**

```
x5=x8 and x7=x9
```

**You must modify your code as such:**

```
x5 = 0.3; x6 = 0.8; x7=1
x8 = (x5+x6) /2 ; x9 = (x6 + x7) / 2
if fx(x6,a) > fx(x5,a) and fx(x6,a) > fx(x7,a):
  x5 = x8
  x7 = x9
```